# Displaying only the most recent activity of an item

Tags: ms-access

I have made a database that tracks the shipping and receiving of the tools that my company has. I am now wanting to make a query that shows only the most recent activity of all the tools. I have a current query that works pretty well but does not do exactly what I would like.

This is currently what the query is showing:
[image: Current Query]

This shows roughly what I want. The only problem is that as you can see bellow it allows Serial_Number to be listed twice. Once for when it was sent and once when it was received. I only want it to display the most recent of the sent and receive.

For example instead of having the serial number 050675 listed once on 2/25/2015 as sent and once on 3/3/2015 as received I would only have the activity on 3/3/2015. And I cannot just limit it to looking for when the item is received because if you look at Serial_Number 1 the most recent item is Sent.

So far I have tried nesting IIf statements and also tried the DMax function and i was unsuccessful on both of them.

This is what I am thinking it should look like. I know this is very very rough but I really do not know how to or what I should use in coding this.

*If Serial_Number <> Unique Then Select Serial_Number Where Recent Date is greater*

This is the table that the data is being pulled from:
[image]

Thank you for any help you might provide.

Comment: `Recieve` should be: `Receive` (not related to the question, just an observation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SELECT a.MaxOfShipID,
           a.Serial_number,
           a.[Recent Date],
           a.[Send_Recieve]
    FROM <tablename> a
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT serial_number,
           MAX([Recent Date]) AS [Recent Date]
    FROM <tablename>
    GROUP BY serial_number
    ) b
         ON a.serial_number = b.serial_number
         AND a.[Recent Date] = b.[Recent Date]
```

**Update:**

In your specific case:

```
SELECT a.MaxOfShipID,
           a.Serial_number,
           a.[Recent Date],
           a.[Send_Recieve]
    FROM tblSend_Recieve a
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT serial_number,
           MAX([Recent Date]) AS [Recent Date]
    FROM tblSend_Recieve
    GROUP BY serial_number
    ) b
         ON a.serial_number = b.serial_number
         AND a.[Recent Date] = b.[Recent Date]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I am misunderstanding this, but the purpose of inner join is when you have data in two different tables that you want to display. All of my data is in a single table that the query would be pulling from. I will update the post with a screen shot of the table I am pulling from. Sorry for not including this info originally.

Comment: That's probably the most common usage of an INNER JOIN but there's nothing stopping you joining a table with itself (or a flavor of itself).

Comment: Sure- what this does is take a set from the table which is the latest [recent date] for each serial_number and then returns the corresponding data for that value. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: I did try it. I obviously edited the code for my case and it gave me a message saying there was an error in the FROM clause.

Comment: SELECT tblSend_Recieve.ShipID,
           tblSend_Recieve.Serial_number,
           tblSend_Recieve.[Recent Date],
           tblSend_Recieve.[Send_Recieve]
FROM <tblSend_Recieve> a
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT serial_number,
       MAX([Recent Date]) [Recent Date]
FROM <tblSend_Recieve>
GROUP BY serial_number
) b
     ON tblSend_Recieve.serial_number = tblSend_Recieve.serial_number
     AND tblSend_Recieve.[Recent Date] = tblSend_Recieve.[Recent Date]

Comment: This is what I edited the code to look like.

Comment: You need to remove the < and > characters from the tablename and leave the a. and b. there  in the ON clause. I'll post a corrected version in the answer shortly.

Comment: Ohh ok. Thank you for the clarification. Now that that is correct I am getting another error but this time in the "MAX([Recent Date])[Recent Date]" line. Syntax error (missing operator) is the error message. Do I need to remove the square brackets inside the parenthesis.

Comment: MAX([Recent Date]) AS [Recent Date] will work. I forgot you have to use the explicit AS in Access.

Comment: Ok so after fixing a few different errors myself it is now asking for a user input for b.Recent Date. This is the edited code 'SELECT a.ShipID,
           a.Serial_Number,
           a.[D],
           a.[Send/Recieve]
FROM tblSend_Recieve a
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT Serial_Number,
       MAX([D]) AS [Recent_Date]
FROM tblSend_Recieve
GROUP BY Serial_Number
) b
     ON a.Serial_Number = b.Serial_Number
     AND a.[D] = b.[Recent Date]'

Comment: The outer query is looking for [Recent Date] where you have AS [Recent_Date] in the subquery now. If these match, it'll work.